# Clamp MovieClip to only be draggable inside stage?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have a MovieClip that I want the user to be able to drag inside the stage, but I don't want it to be able to move outside the stage.

Currently I'm using `this._parent.startDrag();` to allow the MC to be dragged, but I don't know how to stop it from being dragged outside the frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `startDrag` method has some optional parameters to constrain where you can drag, so you could use:

```
this._parent.startDrag(false, 0, 0, Stage.width, Stage.height);
```

There's a [full description](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/00001355.html#401212) in the Adobe AS2 docs